# Rails: Button Group with button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap with my Rails app, and I want to create a button group that contains a button generated using `<%=button_to%>`.

This is what I have:

```
  <div class="btn-group icons">
      <%= button_to(raw("<i class='icon-undo'></i>"), project_steps_path(@project), :method=>:post, :class=> "btn undoIcon disabled", :title=>"undo" )%>
      <button class="btn reorderIcon" title="reorder steps"><%=image_tag("icons/reorder_icon.png")%></button>
      <button class="btn expandIcon" title="expand"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i></button>
  </div>
```

I expected the `<%= button_to%>` to generate something like `<button class=...>` in html, but instead I got the following:

```
<div class="btn-group icons">
      <form action="/projects/18/steps" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input class="btn undoIcon disabled" title="undo" type="submit" value="&lt;i class='icon-undo'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="waRzPnaIUfWBt+sAAQR5STOnilLXhirOx/GaE1i1kFI="></div></form>
      <button class="btn reorderIcon" title="reorder steps"><img alt="Reorder_icon" src="/assets/icons/reorder_icon.png"></button>
      <button class="btn expandIcon" title="expand"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i></button>
</div>
```

Which yields the following on my page:

[image]

How can I create a button using `<%=button_to raw()%>` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by replacing `button_to` with `link_to`

Comment: This it not a valid option because there is a reason why using button_to instead of link_to when sending the parameters, as button_to creates a form.

Answer (score 1):

You need a bit of CSS. Here's what I do:

```html
<div class='btn-group form-btn-group'>
  <%= button_to 'btn1', '#', class: 'btn', form_class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <%= button_to 'btn2', '#', class: 'btn', form_class: 'btn btn-default' %>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

- The `<form>` element needs the `.btn` class but should leave space for the actual `<button>`
- Unstyle the `<button>` element

```css
.form-btn-group > .btn {
  padding: 0;
}
.form-btn-group > .btn > .btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```